How do I exclude divs that have a name link?
My sample HTML markup is below. In each of the three nested sets of divs, I'm removing all <p> tags except for the first <p>.
But now I find I want to not remove all the <p> tags from just the first nested divs that have the anchor link a name="123"
How do I use an if statement and the name="123" attribute to exclude the first set of nested divs from having all their <p> tags removed?
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rbo6gtLd/
Edit 10/4/24
Thanks to Phil for his answer, but I want to use the format of my original function. But this updated jQuery doesn't work:
$('.post-body').each(function() {
  const $this = $(this);
  if ($(this).find('a[name="123"]').length == 0) {
    $(this).find('p').not(":first").remove();
  }
}); 


This original jQuery doesn't work:
$('.post-body').each(function() {
  const $this = $(this);
  if ($(this).closest('[name="123"]').length == 0) {
    $(this).find('p').not(":first").remove();
  }
});

HTML:
<div class="post">
  <a name="123"></a>
  <h3 class="post-title">Post</h3>
  <div class="NewPermalinkUrl">Text</div>
  <div class="post-body">
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>  <!-- fix function so this isn't removed -->
    <p>Content</p>  <!-- fix function so this isn't removed -->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="post">
  <a name="456"></a>
  <h3 class="post-title">Post</h3>
  <div class="NewPermalinkUrl">Text</div>
  <div class="post-body">
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>      <!-- this is currently removed -->
    <p>Content</p>      <!-- this is currently removed -->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="post">
  <a name="789"></a>
  <h3 class="post-title">Post</h3>
  <div class="NewPermalinkUrl">Text</div>
  <div class="post-body">
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>     <!-- this is currently removed -->
    <p>Content</p>     <!-- this is currently removed -->
  </div>
</div>


Can you add an expected output example too?

Cant understand what you're asking, the  that you marked has nothing to do with this. Also .closest() is wrong, use .siblings()

Thanks! I edited my question to make it more clear.

The problem is that .closest() travels hierarchically.
You can use jQuery's :not and :has selectors to exclude the .post element then search within that for the <p> tags you want to remove.
You can also use the p:nth-child(n+2) selector to target every <p> tag after the first within each block.
$('.post:not(:has(a[name="123"])) .post-body p:nth-child(n+2)').remove();

However, you can achieve exactly the same thing purely with CSS which is objectively faster and prevents flash of unstyled content.


.post { border: 1px solid; margin: 1rem 0; padding: 0.5rem; }
.post-title { margin: 0 0 0.5rem; }
.NewPermalinkUrl { color: blue; text-decoration: underline; }

.post:not(:has(a[name="123"])) .post-body p:nth-child(n+2) {
  /* display: none; */
  text-decoration: line-through; /* just for demonstration */
}
<div class="post">
  <a name="123"></a>
  <h3 class="post-title">Post</h3>
  <div class="NewPermalinkUrl">Text</div>
  <div class="post-body">
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Not removed</p>
    <p>Not removed</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="post">
  <a name="456"></a>
  <h3 class="post-title">Post</h3>
  <div class="NewPermalinkUrl">Text</div>
  <div class="post-body">
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>To be removed</p>
    <p>To be removed</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="post">
  <a name="789"></a>
  <h3 class="post-title">Post</h3>
  <div class="NewPermalinkUrl">Text</div>
  <div class="post-body">
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>To be removed</p>
    <p>To be removed</p>
  </div>
</div>




Thanks for managing to guess what I meant :) ! Your answer and suggestions make sense. I want to try and fix my original function and then I'll try the pure CSS method.

@BlueDogRanch for that you'll want to use something like $('.post').each(...) with a check on $(this).find('a[name="123"]').length

use .prevAll()

Get all preceding siblings of each element in the set of matched
elements, optionally filtered by a selector, in the reverse document
order.

more about jQuery Traversing


$('.post-body').each(function() {
  const $this = $(this);
  if ($(this).prevAll('[name="123"]').length == 0) {
    $(this).find('p').not(":first").remove();
  }
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post">
  <a name="123"></a>
  <h3 class="post-title">Post</h3>
  <div class="NewPermalinkUrl">Text</div>
  <div class="post-body">
    <p>Content1</p>
    <p>Content1</p>  <!-- fix function so this isn't removed -->
    <p>Content1</p>  <!-- fix function so this isn't removed -->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="post">
  <a name="456"></a>
  <h3 class="post-title">Post</h3>
  <div class="NewPermalinkUrl">Text</div>
  <div class="post-body">
    <p>Content2</p>
    <p>Content2</p>      <!-- this is currently removed -->
    <p>Content2</p>      <!-- this is currently removed -->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="post">
  <a name="789"></a>
  <h3 class="post-title">Post</h3>
  <div class="NewPermalinkUrl">Text</div>
  <div class="post-body">
    <p>Content3</p>
    <p>Content3</p>     <!-- this is currently removed -->
    <p>Content3</p>     <!-- this is currently removed -->
  </div>
</div>




Thanks, IDK, but that still doesn't want to work for me on my live site or here: https://jsfiddle.net/rbo6gtLd/. What could be the difference?

on jsfiddle you need to remove the // at the top of the script, and make sure jQuery is included.

Thanks! That does work; I found that there is a conflicting function on my live site.
